# Using string library in C++

Tags: c++, string, netbeans

I'm working in Netbeans, programming in C++, and I have a problem:
My program worked perfect in visual, but once I copied it to Netbeans, the `strlen` and `strcpy` (functions of string library) don't work.

The compiler says:

```
unable to resolve identifer strlen
error: 'strlen' was not declared in this scope.
```

I have done `#include <string>`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which header exactly have you included?

Comment: cstring works, but are you sure it's not of C?

Comment: `strlen` and `strcpy` are C funtions.

Answer (score 3):

Have you done

```
#include <cstring>  or 

#include <string.h>
```

Also check if the gcc or cygwin compiler is properly configured with netbeans

Comment: This - if you're compiling in C++ mode, make sure you use the <cstring> header. <string.h> might actually be evaluated to the STL string, which is not what you want.

Comment: Also if including cstring these functions will be put into std namespace

Comment: @IneQuation: That should *never* be the case, if you have encountered it then you are working with a broken C++ implementation. The standard in appendix D.5 clearly states that the C++ standard library must offer `<string.h>` (and 24 other headers) for compatibility with C.

Answer (score -1):

Besides using

```
#include <cstring>
```

also make sure you have put

```
using namespace std;
```

or

```
using std::strlen;
using std::strcpy;
```

ahead your program